# Extension icon click event not working manifest version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onclick

I wanted to do listen for the event when the user clicks on my extension icon on any tab. I did some research but found out that lots of the actions are depreciated and I could only found this method which said that it should work.

manifest.json

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Messages",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description of my extension",
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "tabs", "tabCapture", "storage", "cookies"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Click Me"
       
    },

    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
      "accepts_tls_channel_id": true
    },
    
    
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
    
  }
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => { 
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'popup.html'
      });

      console.log('cow')
     });
```

When I click on the extension icon on a site, nothing is happening, I checked the console log of the server worker by going to the chrome extension setting and finding my extension, nothing was logged there.

What's the working solution in order to listen for the extension click event

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `default_popup` setting in your manifest, it will override the onClicked event listener.  Removing that line should allow the event to fire and open the `popup.html` file in a new tab instead.

You may also need to modify your listener slightly and use `chrome.runtime.getURL` to get the correct path to your file.

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html")
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no need for chrome.runtime.getURL in chrome.tabs.created.